# How to add a global state store in a Spring Cloud Stream application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to configure a global state store in a Spring Cloud Stream application but it fails with :

Exception in thread "svc-toa-app-datainteg-io-dev-fd2e1a47-0758-4b95-9b2e-022ca4df95ca-
StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology:
Topic is unknown to the topology. This may happen if different KafkaStreams instances of
the same application execute different Topologies. Note that Topologies are only identical if all operators are added in the same order.

Following the official documentation I added the following to configure the state store :

```java
 @Bean
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer() {
        return factoryBean -> {
            if (factoryBean.getStreamsConfiguration().getProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG)
                           .equals(applicationId)) {
                try {

                    final var keyValueStore = new KeyValueStoreBuilder<>(
                        Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(PRODUCT_INFO_STORE),
                        productInfoKeySerde(),
                        productInfoValueSerde(),
                        Time.SYSTEM
                    );

                    final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = factoryBean.getObject();

                    streamsBuilder.addGlobalStore(
                        keyValueStore.withLoggingDisabled(),
                        productInfoTopic,
                        Consumed.with(productInfoKeySerde(), productInfoValueSerde()),
                        ProductGlobalStateStoreProcessor::new
                    );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And I have a processor where I want to use the state store :

```java
public class ProductGlobalStateStoreProcessor implements Processor<ProductInfoKey, ProductInfo, Void, Void> {
    KeyValueStore<ProductInfoKey, ProductInfo> stateStore;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext<Void, Void> context) {
        stateStore = context.getStateStore(ProductGlobalStateStoreConfiguration.PRODUCT_INFO_STORE);
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Record<ProductInfoKey, ProductInfo> record) {
        stateStore.put(record.key(), record.value());
    }
}
```

I'm a little lost on what I'm missing, I've tried to add a gktable binding in the properties but it does not change anything.

Comment: Nothing stands out as obvious. Any chance you can create a minimal self-contained sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I've made a simple reproducer (https://github.com/lucas-dclrcq/spring-cloud-stream-global-state-store-reproducer)... but it works in this simplified version.... :D

Answer (score 1):

I've found my issue : another instance was running with the same application id.

Since I added a new source node for the global state store, topologies were different and that's why it would not start.

Comment: Glad you found the issue!

Comment: Hey, good to hear, that you found a solution. We currently have the same problem in our project. Could you maybe provide your solution? To us it's not quite clear how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have exactly the same error : Invalid topology: Topic is unknown to the topology. ?